# Formatting or Inserting Line Break into Query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am calling data from a database. All data is being called from one table and it is displaying as: for example:
Mark is a boy,James is a boy,Trin is a girl,Temi is a girl,.....

I want to achieve:

Mark is a boy

James is a boy

Trin is a girl

Temi is a girl

How would I format this code to achieve that?

```
string query= "INSERT INTO education (institutionname,programme,graduationdate,certawarded) 
               VALUES ('" + txtboxinstname.Text + "', '" + txtboxprogramme.Text + "', '" + txtboxgraddate.Text + "', '" + txtboxcertawarded.Text + "')";

command = new MySqlCommand(dy_query, con);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: SQL is not for pretty printing/formatting. Store data in normalized fashion only. Use your application code (C#) to handle formatting requirements.

Comment: Don't construct SQL statements by concatenating strings. What would happen if someone entered `'; drop table education; //` in the `txtboxcertawarded` field? That's how SQL Injection attacks happen

Comment: As for displaying the results, that's the job of HTML and the view code of the MVC application, not the query's. In any case though, an `INSERT` statement doesn't return data and can't be used to display anything.

Comment: Finally, HTML treats newlines as whitespace. This means that even if one of those fields contained a newline, the text would all appear in a single line when displayed in a web page. You *can't* change that by changing the SQL query.

Comment: Did I misunderstand? The subject made me think the question was about "formatting" the query itself. Did you want to format the results?

Comment: @Panagiotis i use the select query for getting the data from the database and that is when I get the display I was talking about above

Comment: Yes @Joshua, thats what I want. to format the results in the format stated above

Comment: @StephenPokoo you *can't*. HTML treats newlines, tabs etc as space. If you simply output a newline in an HTML page it will appear as a single space. You can use the `<pre></pre>` tags around the string to have it appear in a fixed width font with newlines, the way code snippets appear in SO. Or you can replace newlines with `<br>` characters

Comment: @StephenPokoo perhaps a better idea would be to use a text editor control/widget that generates HTML or some other markup from the user's input and handles the newline conversion itself.

Comment: @StephenPokoo you're getting back a single string formatted "Mark is a boy,James is a boy,etc,etc..." or you're getting back a result set where each of those strings is a separate item? It would be useful if you could post the query you're using to get those results, as well as your view. A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).

> To indicate that a string literal is to be interpreted verbatim. The @ character in this instance defines a verbatim string literal. Simple escape sequences (such as "\" for a backslash), hexadecimal escape sequences (such as "\x0041" for an uppercase A), and Unicode escape sequences (such as "\u0041" for an uppercase A) are interpreted literally. Only a quote escape sequence ("") is not interpreted literally; it produces a single quotation mark. Additionally, in case of a verbatim interpolated string brace escape sequences ({{ and }}) are not interpreted literally; they produce single brace characters. The following example defines two identical file paths, one by using a regular string literal and the other by using a verbatim string literal. This is one of the more common uses of verbatim string literals.

You should also not be using string concatenation to build a SQL query. Especially if you're taking input directly from the user. This opens you up to a [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, you should be using parameters.

```csharp
string query = @"INSERT INTO education
(institutionname,programme,graduationdate,certawarded)
VALUES
(@institutionname,@programme,@graduationdate,@certawarded)";

command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

// I'm not familiar with MySqlCommand. I'm assuming it is similar to SqlCommand, but the
// Parameters property and the AddWithValue method my be named something else. You'll
// have to check for yourself.
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("institutionname", txtboxinstname.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("programme", txtboxprogramme.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("graduationdate", txtboxgraddate.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("certawarded", txtboxcertawarded.Text);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you Joshua, I will implement above. Do you also have solution to my question?